# Doing a collection find in PyMongo and has no effect

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi I was facing a problem when I doing PyMongo.

keywords is a user input by `list(input().split())`

When I doing the `results = post_collection.find()`

I tried four different statement after the find bracket,

1. `{"Title": keyword} or {"Body": keyword} or {"Tags": keyword}`
2. `{"title": keyword} or {"body": keyword} or {"tags": keyword}`
3. `"Title": {"$in": keywords}} or {"Body": {"$in": keywords}} or {"Tags": {"$in": keywords}`
4. `{}`

1,2,3 gives me no response, the `results.count()` return 0 to me , and it will never goes into next `'for posts in results'` loop, it will just skip the for loop and keep going to the next input section.
4 returns me all the posts in my json file opened in the beginning.

I was wondering why I was having that problem, and I am struggling about it the whole day.

Thank you for your time

Below is part of my code.
[part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5jMd.png)

Part of document
{
"Id": "1",
"PostTypeId": "1",
"AcceptedAnswerId": "9",
"CreationDate": "2010-08-17T19:22:37.890",
"Score": 16,
"ViewCount": 28440,
"Body": "

What is the hardware and software differences between Intel and PPC Macs?

\n",
"OwnerUserId": "10",
"LastEditorUserId": "15",
"LastEditDate": "2010-09-08T15:12:04.097",
"LastActivityDate": "2017-09-21T12:16:56.790",
"Title": "What is the difference between Intel and PPC?",
"Tags": "",
"AnswerCount": 9,
"CommentCount": 0,
"FavoriteCount": 6,
"ContentLicense": "CC BY-SA 2.5"
},

Comment: can you show us an example of a document in your mongodb collection?

Comment: @Tobini have done it

Answer (score 0):

The `or` statement doesn't work like this in mongoDb. Read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Here is the query

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "title": keyword
    },
    {
      "body": keyword
    }
    {
      "tags": keyword
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tkk_yCM3G0T)

Comment: Sorry ,it still not work , if I use or like this , it still stay the same, it return me nothing , result.count give me 0 and it just pass the for loop and going to next. Also I have tried that if I just put 'title':keyword and no 'or', it still not work which means it is not the problem about 'or'

Comment: Since you've updated with a example document. You have to use `Title` and not `title`. Mongo is case sensitive on field name

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is under `print(3)`. In your mongo request, the way you are passing the `keyword` is actually invalid, because this one is blocked in the scope of `for loop` on top of it. So the mongo request can't reach the correct keyword. The solution is to push all the code under `print(keyword)`, in the first `for loop`. Like this:

```
for keyword in keywords:
    print(keyword)
    print(3)
    results = posts_collection.find({"$or": [{"Title": keyword}, {"Body": keyword}, {"Tags": keyword}]})
    print(results)
    print(results.count())
    print(4)
    for posts in results:
        print(5)
        if posts['PostTypeId'] == 1:
            print(posts['titlse']) # ...
        else:
            print(1)
            continue
```